# Line to line voltage

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, power-engineering

I have a question regarding power electronics. What is the meaning of 'line to line voltage' what does it tell us and how can this be calculated. Say I have a three phase system how would one find the line to line voltage for this system?

Comment: Electrical stuff should go to [EE StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). In fact the question [has been asked before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94108/what-does-the-line-to-line-voltage-mean/94128#:~:text=The%20line%20to%20line%20voltage%20is%20the%20voltage%20between%20any,phase%20wires%20ABC%2C%20e.g.%20Vab.). // When you calculate it, take the phase into account.

Answer (score 0):

A three-phase system has one neutral wire and three phase wires.

The line-to-line voltage is the voltage between any two of the three phase wires in your three-phase system. It can be measured via a voltmeter in VAC mode with leads clipped to any two of the three phase wires.

If you are concerned with converting between line-to-line and line-to-neutral voltage, check out [this source](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YGeyCAG&l=en-US).

For more information on three-phase power (and for a good laugh), check out this [Electroboom video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quABfe4Ev3s&lc=Ugy2IqD4c-2MvzZTNa14AaABAg&ab_channel=ElectroBOOM).

Comment: For a conventional 3-phase system, the line-to-line voltage is √3 times the line-to-neutral voltage.  √3 is approximately 1.73.  So for a 230V L-N supply, the line-to-line is 400V.